# Recursive mapping using RKObjectMapping?

Tags: ios, rkobjectmapping

How to convert custom object(say objectType1) containing some properties and array of another custom object(say objectType2), into dictionary, using  using RKObjectMapping.

Basically I need to save a custom object in NSUserDeafults.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromMaping {

RKObjectMapping * itemMapping = [RUserObject mapping];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:itemMapping.inverseMapping objectClass:[self class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [RKObjectParameterization parametersWithObject:self requestDescriptor:requestDescriptor error:nil];

[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if (obj == [NSNull null]) {
        [dictionary setValue:nil forKey:key];
    }
}];


return dictionary;
}
```

Consider the example

```
@interface ObjectType1 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray * objectType2Array; // array of ObjectType2

@interface ObjectType2 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString * address;
```

Now I want to get the `NSDictionary` for a Object of type `ObjectType1`

Comment: @Wain 
Can you please help?

Comment: What is `if !self return nil`?

Comment: Oops! That was a mistake. Have removed it.

Comment: So I don't see anything in your mapping about relationships/nesting. And what does user defaults have to do with posting and a request descriptor?

Comment: I have edited the question. All I want is to save a custom object in NSUserDefaluts using RKobject Mapping. If there is another alternative, please suggest. @Wain

Answer (score 0):

You aren't making any network requests as far as I can tell so you don't need a request descriptor. You're just trying to locally convert a graph of model objects into JSON so you should be using `RKMapperOperation`.

Comment: Can you suggest some sample code to save custom object in NSUserDefaults using RestKit.